# Defining functions that output a figure, but several figures outputted in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Sorry for the confusing title. The idea is, I'm making functions that do a bit of data cleaning, then output a figure. The problem I'm having is they tend to either output repeats of the figure, or several empty plots.

The first offender:

```
# Draw Categorical Plot
def draw_cat_plot():
    # Create DataFrame for cat plot using `pd.melt` using just the values from 'cholesterol', 'gluc', 'smoke', 'alco', 'active', and 'overweight'.
    df_cat = pd.melt(df, id_vars = 'cardio', value_vars = ['cholesterol', 'gluc', 'smoke', 'alco', 'active', 'overweight'])
    df_cat['total'] = 0


    # Group and reformat the data to split it by 'cardio'. Show the counts of each feature. You will have to rename one of the columns for the catplot to work correctly.
    df_cat = df_cat.groupby(['cardio', 'variable', 'value']).count().reset_index()

    # Draw the catplot with 'sns.catplot()'
    bar = sns.catplot(x='variable', y = 'total', hue = 'value', col = 'cardio', data = df_cat, kind = 'bar')
    fig = bar.fig


    # Do not modify the next two lines
    fig.savefig('catplot.png')
    return fig
```

This (correctly) outputs the following:

[image]

But, it outputs two copies of it, vertically, which I don't want. Essentially this:

[image]

[image]

What am I getting wrong? I'd assume it's something very simple.

The second issue I'm having is with a Seaborn heatmap:

```
# Draw Heat Map
def draw_heat_map():
    # Clean the data
    #df_heat = df.drop("bmi", axis = 1)
    df_heat = df
    df_heat = df_heat[df_heat["ap_lo"] <= df_heat["ap_hi"]]
    df_heat = df_heat[df_heat["height"] >= df_heat["height"].quantile(0.025)]
    df_heat = df_heat[df_heat["height"] <= df_heat["height"].quantile(0.975)]
    df_heat = df_heat[df_heat["weight"] >= df_heat["weight"].quantile(0.025)]
    df_heat = df_heat[df_heat["weight"] <= df_heat["weight"].quantile(0.975)]
    
    # Calculate the correlation matrix
    corr = df_heat.corr()


    # Generate a mask for the upper triangle
    mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(corr, dtype=bool))


    # Set up the matplotlib figure
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10, 12))

    # Draw the heatmap with 'sns.heatmap()'
    sns.heatmap(corr, mask = mask, vmax = 0.3, center = 0, annot = True,
           square = True, linewidths=0.5, cbar_kws={"shrink": 0.5})


    # Do not modify the next two lines
    fig.savefig('heatmap.png')
    return fig
```

This outputs:

[image]

[image]

As before, I just want it to output one copy. What am I getting wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: The functions look okay enough, so my bet is on something outside from them. How are you calling these functions? Are you doing anything with the figures returned by them? Do the multiple plots appear on the screen, or on the figure saved (e.g. `'heatmap.png'`)?

Comment: In the Jupyter notebook, if the final line of the cell returns a matplotlib figure, it will be shown in the output. This is a separate mechanism from the inline matplotlib display hook.  That's probably what's happening here.